# Adding a correct routing roule

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add a new routing roule to make my application do urls like these: http://domain/controller/action/parameter. Right now the application make urls like this: http://domain/controller/action?param=XXX

Right now I have the following code:

Button actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", "Controller", new { param = "1" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })
```

And my routing roules in RouteConfig.cs is:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

What do I have to do to make my application make the correct url (http://domain/controller/action/parameter)? What are the modifications that I have to do to make this possible?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: It is already implemented. Try to use `new { id = "1" }` in actionlink

Comment: Correct. But if I want to put as a parameter a string? How can I get this?

Comment: Put url like: http://domain/controller/action/string instead of http://domain/controller/action/number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change to id

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", "Controller", new { id = "1" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })
```

Or maintain the param and change the route config

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{param}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", param = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route arguments (param) have to be the same as in routing map (id):

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", "Controller", new { id = "1" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })
```